# Reference request: modern type-theoretic logic

Tags: logic, reference-request, type-theory

I'm teaching myself type theory and logic with nlab.

I would like to know which published textbook covers this content.

Examples of what is included

- [context](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/context) and [term in context](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/term+in+context)
- [typed predicate logic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/typed+predicate+logic)
- [propositional equality](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/propositional+equality)
- [dependent type theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dependent+type+theory)

Comment: Maybe useful: William Farmer, Simple Type Theory: A Practical Logic for Expressing and Reasoning About Mathematical Ideas (2023, Springer) as well as **Ch.2 A Brief Introduction to Constructive Type Theory** of Shahid Rahman & Ansten Klev & Nicolas Clerbout, Immanent Reasoning or Equality in Action: A Plaidoyer for the Play Level (2018, Springer)